# How to delete a XML tag from XML file without Hard coding the tag Name

Tags: java, jquery, xml

I need to delete all **OBJECT** TAG in XML file using Java. I can able to delete the **OBJECT** Tag when I enter parent Tag Name(**SPAN**) directly Hard code into the source code("span"), But I need to delete the Tag without hard code Parent Tag. If I hard code, I  can able to delete only the **Object Tag** inside **span** Tag. I need to **delete** all the  in XML even it may be inside another parent Tag, Without **Hard code** the Parent tag in Source code. I need to delete all **Object** tag available inside both **span** tag and also **score** tag in Sample XML File. For Sample XML File view the below **Image**.

Java Program

```
public class XmlObject {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filePath = "/Users/myXml/Sample.xml";
    File xmlFile = new File(filePath);
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
    try {
        dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        deleteElement(doc);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("/Users/myXml/Sample_ObjDelete.xml"));
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        System.out.println("XML file updated successfully");

    } catch (SAXException | ParserConfigurationException | IOException | TransformerException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void deleteElement(Document doc) {
    NodeList RootElement = doc.getElementsByTagName("assessmentItem");

    int getRootElementLength = RootElement.getLength();

        System.out.println("getRootElementLength "+getRootElementLength);

        for(int k = 0; k < getRootElementLength; k++){
            System.out.println("2");
            Node nNode = RootElement.item(0);

            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
            NodeList object = eElement.getElementsByTagName("span");
            Element obj = null;


    for(int i=0; i<object.getLength();i++){
        obj = (Element) object.item(i);
        int leng = obj.getElementsByTagName("object").getLength();
            System.out.println("object:" +leng);
            for(int j=0; j<leng;j++){
                Node objectNode = obj.getElementsByTagName("object").item(k);
                (obj).removeChild(objectNode);
            }
    }
    }

}

}
```

```html
<qualityTest>
<responseDeclaration>
<correctResponse>
<value>QualityTest</value>
</correctResponse>
</responseDeclaration>
<itemBody>
<sampleTest>
<p>Who is president of uganda?</P>
<span>
<object>
Yoweri Museveni</object>
<span>
<object>
Raúl Castro
</Object>
</span>
</sampleTest>
</itemBody>
<score>
<object>
Yingluck Shinawatra
</Object>
</score>
</qualityTest>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't really understand what you are trying to achieve! Do you need to remove all XmlElements named span?

Comment: I need to remove object tag inside the xml. Even it may be below to different parent tag. please see the image which i given below. Sir

Comment: Please edit your question to include the XML file's contents as text, not an image.  We can't test your code on an image.

Comment: @VGR: I changed the image into text.

Comment: @ParkerHalo: Sir, The code which you given working Fine. Thank you very much. But now I cant find the code which you given in this page. Please post your code again. It will be useful for others.

Comment: @TamilveeraCholan, what if the xml have other tag which we don't know in advance? Is is possible to get only text between those tag e.g. QualityTest,Who is president of uganda?, Yoweri Museveni, Raúl Castro ... without removing each tag one by one?

Answer (score 1):

You should walk the xml-tree recursively and remove all occurencies of any object element:

```
private static void deleteElement(Node someNode) {
    NodeList childs = someNode.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < childs.getLength();) {
        Node child = childs.item(i);
        if (child.getNodeType() == Document.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            if (child.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("object")) {
                child.getParentNode().removeChild(child);
                continue;
            } else {
                deleteElement(child);
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

This little code snippet will remove any xml-tag named "object" in any depth of the tree.

Comment: Sir, Why you used (Node someNode) as a parameter in deleteElement method ? In program  i use (Document doc) as a parameter.

Comment: Sir, I changed as you said,But I got NULL POINTER Exception. I use Node instead of root. But I am facing Null pointer Exception. 'Node node =doc.getDocumentElement(); deleteElement(node);' I need to change any other code.

Comment: Sir, I got a solution. Thank you ParkerHalo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Xpath and XpathExpression for going **Span** and **Score** tags

```
  XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression = "//span";           
NodeList spanNodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

spanNodeList will give you all span nodes. so you iterate the spanNodeList and delete the span element like below code

```
for (int i = 0; i < spanNodeList .getLength(); i++) {
            Node spanItem= spanNodeList .item(i);

            Node parentNode = spanItem.getParentNode();
            parentNode.removeChild(spanItem);
}
```

and same for **Score** tag also

Comment: Now In this xml file object is inside span tag. But i have some object tag in other  parent Tag. What should I do...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an XPath to select all elements except `<object>` elements.  For instance, you can put this in a file named `strip-object.xsl`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="//object"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Notice the first template rule, which does nothing with `object` nodes, effectively discarding them.  The second template rule, which takes effect for all other nodes, copies them exactly.

To make use of it, initialize your Transformer with the .xsl file:

```
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(
    new StreamSource(new File("/Users/myXml/strip-object.xsl")));
```

If you only want to strip out `object` elements which are children of `span` and `score` elements, you can change the XPath expression:

```
  <xsl:template match="//span/object|//score/object"/>
```